# How to know which client is sending message to the server

Tags: python, client-server

Following is my server code so far

```
def multipleClients():
    global counter=0
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    counter=counter+1
    all_clients.append(conn)
    print "is connected :D :)", addr
    i=0
    name= conn.recv(1024)
    while True:
        while i<counter:
            if all_clients[counter] == conn  #comparing the current client with the one which sent the message:
                name=conn.recv(1024)
                data= conn.recv(1024)
                if not data:
                    break
                print repr(name),":"
                print "message is :", repr(data)
                for c in all_clients:
                    n= name,":"
                    c.sendall(data)
    counter=0
```

Above is only the multithreaded function accepting connections etc.
I want to check that which client has sent the message because only one client is allowed to send a message at a time. Moreover, the client which has sent the message can only send message again when all other clients have sent messages in their turns. I do know that my above approach "if statement" is incorrect.
In above code, server is just receiving message and name from client and sending it to all the clients. And connected clients info is stored in list

Comment: Have you seen [chatserver.py](https://github.com/circuits/circuits/blob/master/examples/chatserver.py)?

Comment: You seem to have it backwards. Since this is multithreaded, there will be multiple threads running this function. Each thread will only ever talk to one client (the one you get from `s.accept()`), so when you `recv` there is no doubt who it came from.

Comment: @theSmallNothing I get your point. But how can I put a lock on other threads except for just one from main()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I get what your looking for. What you want is a system which is like a *round-robin* messaging system, where each client has one *turn* to get its message retransmitted.

In order to get this to work you need someway of identifying which thread's *turn* it is.

The way I'd do this is to have the main function increment some global variable which the threads could compare against their id (which could be their client info index in the `all_clients` array).

If the id matched, the thread could then `recv`. The main function would need someway of knowing when to increment to the next thread id, so we could use an [`Event`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#event-objects) instance and `set` it after receiving a message.

```
# in this example, current_id and recvd_event are global variables, since global variables
#  are generally considered a bad coding practice they also could be wrapped in a class and
#  passed in.

def multipleClients():
    conn, addr = s.accept()

    # the number of clients at this moment is unique, so we can use it as an id
    client_id = len(all_clients) 
    all_clients.append(conn)

    # .. do other stuff ..

    while True:
        if client_id == current_id:
            # receive, retransmit, etc..
            recvd_event.set()

def main():
    global current_id
    # .. set up server ..
    current_id = 0
    recvd_event = threading.Event()
    while True:
        # .. select incoming connection ..
            # .. create thread ..
        if recvd_event.isSet():
            # received a message, next thread's turn
            # increments current_id and wraps around at end of client list
            current_id = (current_id + 1) % len(all_clients)
            recvd_event.clear()
```